# How to send totally different HTML content based on screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to send separate content to the client, based on screen resolution.

In this moment, all the content is delivered the page `index.php` and, through CSS I display or not the parts I want.

The drawback is that: the whole content of the page is always delivered to the client. Just the display changes. This increase the traffic to mobiles, for nothing.

My goal is to be able, always calling `index.php`, to really deliver different HTML content based on resolution, so that, the traffic for the mobile devices can drastically be reduced (on my case is a list and 10 CSS lines rather that tones of JS, different CSS etc etc etc) and to Desktops, it is sent only what they really need to be displayed

Is it possible to do so using PHP/JS and, at the same time, be Google SEO Compliant?

Comment: perhaps using ajax? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Ideally you would always show the content that would be on all devices, and load the extra using ajax. You could just redirect instead.

Comment: true, a redirect would probably be best.

Comment: It wouldn't be best, it would be easiest.

Comment: But a redirect which is not 301, seems not a good stuff for Google ... it seems the rank will be penalized ... and a 301 I guess is not possible to do with JS. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sniff the user agent string to try to decide if a user is on a mobile device, and then return different content that way, but be aware that it's not always accurate.

To avoid having to detect all of the types of device yourself, you could use [Mobile_Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) or something similar.

```
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) {
    // all mobile devices excluding tablets (i.e. phones)
    include('phone_template.php');
} else if($detect->isTablet()) {
    // all tablets
    include('tablet_template.php');
} else {
    // everything else
    include('desktop_template.php');
}
```

Again, this works based on the user agent string, which is spoofable (hell chrome lets you do it in developer tools to test different screen sizes).

It won't be perfect, but it might get you by.

Comment: Excellent solution Samlev.  I employed a bit to set up everything, in order to avoid that desktop.php and portable.php are loaded directly: users should pass by index.php otherwise they get re-directed .
And it works excellently. thank you so much.
Now I'm busy with the remaining optimization